# How to intercept socket traffic on solaris?

Tags: solaris, tcp, debugging

I'm not very familiar with Solaris, so maybe there are tools that I don't know about. I need to debug the communication between two components on the same machine, talking to each other using a normal TCP socket.

Now there seem to be two tools available, one known from linux called `tcpdump`, the other one being a solaris utility called `snoop`. Unfortunately, at the client's site, there are a lot of restrictions and whatnot, so using these tools is not allowed / possible.

So, what I figured is that I could change the listening port of the server process to something else and have a tool like `netcat` act as a proxy on the actual port while forwarding the traffic to the "real" server process, so I can dump the communication between those components.

Is there a tool that does this - preferably outputting a known format like tcpdump's? Or how else would you go about this?

Comment: Are you using Solaris 10 or later?

Comment: It's Solaris 10.

Answer (score 1):

`snoop` is not an option anyway because it won't work for traffic between two processes on the same host.

[DTrace](http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/dtrace_topics_intro.pdf) is your best bet. For example, here is a [script for capturing traffic between two processes on the same server](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1917840) in `snoop` format. However, this particular script relies on the internal workings of the kernel so it may or may not work with your version of Solaris 10.

Answer (score 1):

> change the listening port of the server process to something else and have a tool like netcat

netcat will do the port forwarding - but not logging the info. However the suorce code is widely available - so if your C skills are up to it, it would be straightforward to add this in. If the prefer Perl - then there's several port forwarders written using that. There's a cpan module [here](http://search.cpan.org/~andypur/POE-Component-Proxy-TCP-1.2/lib/POE/Component/Proxy/TCP.pm).

If the data is travelling across a network and you have physical access to the network (at a point where the data is not encrypted) then you could use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Unfortunately, this happens in a high-security environment, where (if even possible) it would not be allowed to have tools like wireshark around. +1 however on the CPAN link, maybe this could be used.

Comment: @Dave Vogt, I am still puzzling over why it's acceptable to write your own tool (potentially buggy, with unintended 0-day exploits, and no widespread code review) instead of using something open-source (like wireshark) to do presumably the exact same thing.